# Google Chat Bot: Bot reply not seen by both people

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hangouts, hangouts-api

I have created a chat bot for google chat to our gsuite. When I type @DadJokes it returns random dadjoke from an API

Problem is that only I can see the returned joke and I cannot find info about this in the documentation.

Can anyone navigate me to the right path?

Thank you

```
function getDadJoke() {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://icanhazdadjoke.com/', {
    method: 'get',
    headers: { 'Accept': 'text/plain' },
    contentType: 'plain/text',
  });
  
 return response.getContentText();
}

/**
 * Responds to a MESSAGE event in Hangouts Chat.
 *
 * @param {Object} event the event object from Hangouts Chat
 */
function onMessage(event) {
  console.log(getDadJoke());
  return { "text": getDadJoke() };
}

/**
 * Responds to an ADDED_TO_SPACE event in Hangouts Chat.
 *
 * @param {Object} event the event object from Hangouts Chat
 */
function onAddToSpace(event) {
  return { "text": getDadJoke() };
}

/**
 * Responds to a REMOVED_FROM_SPACE event in Hangouts Chat.
 *
 * @param {Object} event the event object from Hangouts Chat
 */
function onRemoveFromSpace(event) {
  console.info("Bot removed from ",(event.space.name ? event.space.name : "this chat"));
}
```

UPDATE

I got it working using async messages, but now others receive the joke sooner then my own message where I typed @DadJokes. So that means i type @DadJokes, chat participants recieve the joke from bot, then they receive my message @DadJokes

```
function getDadJoke() {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://icanhazdadjoke.com/', {
    method: 'get',
    headers: { 'Accept': 'text/plain' },
    contentType: 'plain/text',
  });
  
 return response.getContentText();
}

function sendDadJoke(spaceId) {
 
   var service = OAuth2.createService('chat')
      .setTokenUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token')
      .setPrivateKey(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PRIVATE_KEY)
      .setClientId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
      .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties())
      .setScope(SCOPE);
  
  if (!service.hasAccess()) {
    Logger.log('Authentication error: %s', service.getLastError());
    return;
  }
  
  var url = 'https://chat.googleapis.com/v1/' + spaceId + '/messages';
  
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    method: 'post',
    headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken() },
    contentType: 'application/json',
    payload: JSON.stringify({ "text": getDadJoke() }),
  });
  
}


/**
 * Responds to a MESSAGE event in Hangouts Chat.
 *
 * @param {Object} event the event object from Hangouts Chat
 */
function onMessage(event) {
  
  sendDadJoke(event.space.name);
  
  return {"message": "Okay here it comes!"};
}

/**
 * Responds to an ADDED_TO_SPACE event in Hangouts Chat.
 *
 * @param {Object} event the event object from Hangouts Chat
 */
function onAddToSpace(event) {
 
  sendDadJoke(event.space.name);
  
  return {"message": "Okay here it comes!"};
}

/**
 * Responds to a REMOVED_FROM_SPACE event in Hangouts Chat.
 *
 * @param {Object} event the event object from Hangouts Chat
 */
function onRemoveFromSpace(event) {
  console.info("Bot removed from ",(event.space.name ? event.space.name : "this chat"));
}
```

Comment: What are your Hangouts Chat API configuration setitngs in GCP for your project?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo status - available to users | functionality - works with DM, works in rooms and DM with multiple users | Connection -  Apps Script | Permission - Everyone in *my gsuite*...... In credentials I have also OAuth 2.0 Client IDs  created.

Comment: Are you using the Head deployment, or have you created a new deployment?

Comment: Created new, if i use head it says that i cannot use had for the whole domain.

Comment: What scopes are you using for the project? If you have any, have your other users authorised them? They can do this by messagin the bot and following the prompt

Comment: I don't know what you mean under scopes. About the authorization thing, I am authorized, my coworker also tried the @DadJokes command, he saw the joke, but I did not see, so in theory both of us were authorized. I seen only that he wrote "@DadJokes", and it works like this vice-versa

Comment: What do you have listed when you follow the `File > Project properties > Scopes` menu item fro mthe Apps Script editor?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo "OAuth Scope required by script:
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request"

Comment: Can you add `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chat.bot`?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo Authorization Error
Error 400: invalid_scope
Some requested scopes cannot be shown: [https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chat.bot]

Added this scope using appsscript.json under oauthScopes, then deployed new version, updated app in console to new ID, then tried @ DadJokes, it asked for config then during authorization it threw error above.

Comment: Did you include the `https://www.`?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo yes https://ibb.co/frKKrC3

Comment: You need to *add* the scope, not replace. Make sure to keep `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request` as well

Comment: @RafaGuillermo my bad, but still Error 400: invalid_scope
Some requested scopes cannot be shown: [https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chat.bot, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request]

Comment: @RafaGuillermo i have upgraded the code to send the message async using service user. It works, but a weird thing is happenning. the bot reply shows first then my message. like its sending the reply from bot sooner than my own message where i request the joke

Comment: Are you sure that isn't a result of the API being called when adding the bot to a room? It's not possible for the bot to answer before you message it ;) Also, I think you may need to change the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chat.bot` scope to just `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chat`.

Comment: @RafaGuillermo I am calling api when bot is added to automatically send a joke, so the bot does not need to mentioned twice on the first time. But on further messages  when I mention the bot, the bot sends the message and it's displayed in correct order (in my chat window) but not for the recepient. After i refresh the window the order of messages is wrong. But I can live with that, it's just for fun

Comment: Can you see the timestamps of the messages?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo nah, only the minutes, even if i hover it does not show the seconds or miliseconds. A stupid idea, but is it plausible that the sendDadJoke ajax to fetch the joke + the rest api request that sends the joke as message executes faster (getting saved to google database) than then the message that mentions the bot